# Codeigniter return and display the array result of model function, called by jquery, on my view

Tags: jquery, database, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter in my app. I have an autocomplete drop down that on selection calls a controller function to display further details about the selected dropdown value.

I have used the below syntax successfully to return a single result but now need to return an entire array to the view and display each returned row with multiple columns.

So the syntax for the single result is:

**Controller**

```
function get_link_load_options(){

    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
        $q = strtolower($_POST['data']);
        $data = $this->Sales_model->get_link_load_options($q);
        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data));
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function get_link_load_options($q){
    $this->db->select('TotalCubes,CustomerName,TotalCubes, TreatedCubes');
    $this->db->where('CustomerOrderID', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('Customer_Order_Summary');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['TotalCubes'])); 
       return $row_set;
    }
  }
```

**View Jquery**

```
   $.post('get_link_load_options', {data:substr[1]},function(result) { 
   $('input[name^="totalcubes"]').val(result[0]);
   });
```

So how do I adapt/change this to populate my view with the `get_link_load_options` function results.

Is this the best method or should I be using another method?
Can the entire array `$query` be passed and if so how do I use jquery / javascript to render the array into a table?

When I do the above, I get the response:
`Message:  json_encode(): type is unsupported, encoded as null`

Thanks as always.

Comment: i use only `echo json_encode($data);` for ajax in my service, and probably you can pass `$query` result directly to the `json_encode` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need json for this you can simply do it like this. Just create a div which will be empty at first place. Your jquery result will fill it then like this

Controller

```
function get_link_load_options(){
    $this->load->model('Sales_model');
    if (isset($_POST['data'])){
        $q = strtolower($_POST['data']);
        $data['result'] = $this->Sales_model->get_link_load_options($q);
        $this->load->view('myview',$data);
    }
}
```

JQuery

```
$.post('get_link_load_options', {data:substr[1]},function(result) { 
   $('#div_id').html(result);
});
```

Comment: Hi Raheel, Thanks for helping me...again! so when I look at the server response that I am getting from your code, it is actually loading an entire page worth of source code? Should `'myview'` in your example be a new page that will be loaded inside the div? then I can access the $data content as per normal controller / view functions? or am I way off the mark? Thanks again.

Comment: @Smudger you are right you can simply load a view through controller and pass that view to a div through jquery. That is i think the easiest way

Comment: Thanks Raheel. Question, how can I pass two data values to the controller? something like: `$.post('get_link_load_options', {data:var1,var2},function(result) { `? then in my controller I can use var1 as $q and var2 as $r? is this possible as I'll need to pass multiple variables in order to display the required info in the view? thanks again.

Comment: `$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }).done(function(data) { /* other stuff here */ });` recieve name and time in post on test.php

Comment: Thanks Raheel. using the syntax you provided now,  `$.post("get_link_load_options", { varlatitude: latitude, varlongitude: longitude }).done(function(data) { $('#results').html(result);  }); ` this prints the 2 variable latitude and longitude to my div, not the contents of view `get_link_load_options` any ideas? thanks.

Comment: `$('#results').html(result)` replace this with `$('#results').html(data)`